# Embedded Excel table in Word doc is getting blacked out when printing to PDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, microsoft-word

I am working with a client that has a Word doc that has an Excel table in it. When the user tries to print to PDF using PDFcreator or Acrobat the table gets blacked out in the PDF. Does anyone know what causes this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the Excel table uses a semi-transparent background color?

Is the same problem appearing if you make the table background all-white?

[PDFCreator uses Ghostscript in the background to do the to-PDF-conversion work. Older versions of Ghostscript do have problems with transparancy regions. The most recent version, 8.71, works just fine. Also, transparencies appeared for the first time in PDF-1.4 file format version, and they are not supported in PDF-1.3. Anyway, PDFCReator uses PostScript input from a PostScript printer driver, and PostScript does not support transparancies *at all* {it emulates them by using raster patterns}.... so it could be that the PostScript level is set to 2 instead of 3 in the printer driver settings.]